# Accessing flat list from nested dictionary

Tags: python

I have a nested dictionary which contains list as key-value pairs

```
data ={'Country': {"['USA', 'Russia']":"['A country in North America','A country in Asia']"},'River': {"['Nile', 'Amazon']":"['A river in Africa','A river in South America']"}}
countrylist=[]
temp=[]
country_desc_list=[]
for k in data:
  countrylist.extend(data[k].keys())
  country_desc_list.extend(data[k].values())
  print(countrylist)
  print(country_desc_list)
  countrylist.clear()
  country_desc_list.clear()
```

but the output is like

```
["['USA', 'Russia']"]
["['A country in North America','A country in Asia']"]
["['Nile', 'Amazon']"]
["['A river in Africa','A river in South America']"]
```

I want it to be in the form of a flatlist like

```
['Usa','Russia']
['A country in North America','A country in Asia']
```

I m new to python so even after few searches I couldn't figure it out ...pls help :)

Comment: So you want to extract only the country information and not the river information? Also `"['USA', 'Russia']"` is a string in your dictionary. Do you want a list from that?

Comment: Yes those print statement were supposed to be inside loop but i hurriedly posted over here...and yes I want a separate list of key,value for each nested key-value pair inside main dictionary

Comment: @BotRex You can edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the desired output by:

```
for x,y in data.items():
    for p,q in y.items():
        print(p,q)

#output
['USA', 'Russia'] ['A country in North America','A country in Asia']
['Nile', 'Amazon'] ['A river in Africa','A river in South America']
```

if you print like this:

```
for x,y in data.items():
    for p,q in y.items():
        print(p)
        print(q)

#output
['USA', 'Russia']
['A country in North America','A country in Asia']
['Nile', 'Amazon']
['A river in Africa','A river in South America']
```

Comment: Btw can we still have those p and q in form of list ? Currently their type is 'str'

Comment: yes we can by using `list()` keyword.

Comment: I used it like print(list(p)) and it returned something like this : ['[', "'", 'N', 'i', 'l', 'e', "'", ',', ' ', "'", 'A', 'm', 'a', 'z', 'o', 'n', "'", ']'] separating every characters and symbols
Is there any other way to use list() which idk ?